# features in Brackets editor when writing Sass

Tags: sass, gulp, adobe-brackets

I have only ever used brackets as an editor and really like the live preview which updates after every edit and the ability to edit the CSS whilst inside my HTML document using the quick editor(ctrl+E).
I was just about to start using Sass for the first time and gulp to minify and compile it on save, but this means:

1) live preview won't work unless I save each time as I have to link to the minified CSS file in the head, not the sass file.

2) I can't use the quick edit as there are now so many files in the folders created by gulp that it doesn't go straight to your CSS file, instead gives you a huge list of file options to choose from.

Does this mean I have to do without my 2 favourite features now that I'm using Sass or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

**For your first question:**

I'm not a Bracket user, so i might be wrong. However the Bracket official doc states that preprocessors don't work with [live preview](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Troubleshooting#-live-preview-isnt-working)

But if you use a [file watcher](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#live-preview-with-scssless) to compile your sass (Gulp, Grunt, Webpack, etc) it should enable lie preview of the compiled css.

**For your second question:**
If Gulp i creating several files, are you importing them as partials e.g. prefixing all but your main file with underscore e.g. `_foo.scss` ?